# Single spec duration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Is there a way in RSpec to show every single test duration and not just the total suite duration?

Now we have

> Finished in 7 minutes 31 seconds (files took 4.71 seconds to load)

but I'd like to have something like

```
User accesses home and
 he can sign up (finished in 1.30 seconds)
 he can visit profile (finished in 3 seconds)
 .
 .
 .
Finished in 7 minutes 31 seconds (files took 4.71 seconds to load)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rspec --profile N`, which would show you the top N slowest examples.

Comment: yes I can, but if I have 100 examples in my test suite, it will not help me achieve what I want to.

Comment: @fabersky You can put any number alongside with --profile to profile N examples, check it out

Comment: ok. I downvoted because in your first answer you didn't put the "--profile"

Comment: is there also a way to ONLY show the slowest examples, without the slowest examples groups?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know one

Comment: just one last question: is there a way to "--profile ALL" instead of "--profile N"?

Comment: I think you can achieve that with a custom formatter, check out @Yule's answer

Answer (score 2):

For a quick solution see @maximf's  answer. For an alternative solution, you could write your own rspec formatter, which would give you greater control over what you are measuring.

For example, extnding rspec's base text formatter:

```
RSpec::Support.require_rpec_core "formatters/base_text_formatter"
module RSpec::Core::Formatters
  class TimeFormatter < BaseTextFormatter
    Formatters.register self, :example_started, :example_passed

    attr_accessor :example_start, :longest_example, :longest_time

    def initialize(output)
      @longest_time = 0
      super(output)
    end

    def example_started(example)
       @example_start = Time.now
       super(example)
    end

    def example_passed(example)
       time_taken = Time.now - @example_start
       output.puts "Finished #{example.example.full_description} and took @{Helpers.format_duration(time_taken)}"
       if @time_taken > @longest_time
         @longest_example = example
         @longest_time = time_taken
       end
       super(example)
     end

     def dump_summary(summary) 
       super(summary)
       output.puts 
       output.puts "The longest example was #{@longest_example.example.full_Description} at #{Helpers.format_duration(@longest_time)}"
     end
   end
end
```

Note that this will only log times on passed examples, but you could add an example_failed failed to do similar, it also only works with RSpec 3. This is based on my work on my own formatter: https://github.com/yule/dots-formatter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `rspec --profile N`everytime we run specs (as @maximf said), we can add it to our RSpec configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.profile_examples = 10
end
```